# Grails/Maven build failure

Tags: java, maven, grails

I've generated pom by

```
grails create-pom
```

The xml.pom file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>xxx</groupId>
    <artifactId>xxx</artifactId>
    <packaging>grails-app</packaging>
    <version>0.1</version>
    <name>xxx</name>
    <description>xxx</description>

    <properties>
        <grails.version>2.2.4</grails.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.grails</groupId>
            <artifactId>grails-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${grails.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.grails</groupId>
            <artifactId>grails-test</artifactId>
            <version>${grails.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.grails</groupId>
            <artifactId>grails-plugin-testing</artifactId>
            <version>${grails.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder</groupId>
        <artifactId>http-builder</artifactId>
        <version>0.5.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <!-- ######################################### -->
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>xml-resolver</groupId>
                <artifactId>xml-resolver</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.3-1101.jdbc41</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>

    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-net</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-net</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>

    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spock-grails-support</artifactId>
        <version>0.7-groovy-2.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>

    </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.grails.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat</artifactId>
            <version>${grails.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <type>zip</type>
        </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.grails.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.4</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <type>zip</type>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.grails.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-RC11</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <type>zip</type>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.grails.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>gflyway2</artifactId>
        <version>0.4.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <type>zip</type>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.grails.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>cache</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <type>zip</type>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.grails.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.3</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <type>zip</type>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.grails.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>database-migration</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <type>zip</type>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.grails.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <type>zip</type>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.grails.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>spock</artifactId>
        <version>0.7</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <type>zip</type>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.grails.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <type>zip</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
      <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
      <version>9.3-1101-jdbc41</version>
    </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement />

        <plugins>
            <!-- Disables the Maven surefire plugin for Grails applications, as we have our own test runner -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>true</skip>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>surefire-it</id>
                        <phase>integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <skip>false</skip>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <filesets>
                        <fileset>
                            <directory>plugins</directory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*</include>
                            </includes>
                            <followSymlinks>false</followSymlinks>
                        </fileset>
                    </filesets>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.grails</groupId>
                <artifactId>grails-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${grails.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- Whether for Fork a JVM to run Grails commands -->
                    <fork>true</fork>
                </configuration>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>Codehaus</id>
          <url>http://repository.codehaus.org</url>
        </repository>
           <repository>
            <id>grails</id>
            <name>grails</name>
            <url>http://repo.grails.org/grails/core</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>grails-plugins</id>
            <name>grails-plugins</name>
            <url>http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins</url>
        </repository>

        <!--   -->
        <repository>
            <id>clojars</id>
            <url>http://clojars.org/repo/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
          <id>Codehaus.Snapshots</id>
          <url>http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org</url>
          <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </repository>
        <!--   -->
    </repositories>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>tools</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>java.vendor</name>
                    <value>Sun Microsystems Inc.</value>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
                    <version>${java.version}</version>
                    <scope>system</scope>
                    <systemPath>${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

The build gives the following exception:

```
|Loading Grails 2.2.4
|Configuring classpath

Fatal error forking Grails JVM: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at org.grails.launcher.GrailsLauncher.launch(GrailsLauncher.java:150)
        at org.grails.maven.plugin.tools.ForkedGrailsRuntime.main(ForkedGrailsRuntime.java:168)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.grails.launcher.GrailsLauncher.launch(GrailsLauncher.java:144)
        ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving overridden method "org.apache.tools.ant.helper.ProjectHelper2$RootHandler.setDocumentLocator(Lorg/xml/sax/Locator;)V" the class loader (instance of org/grails/launcher/RootLoader) of the current class,
 org/apache/tools/ant/helper/ProjectHelper2$RootHandler, and its superclass loader (instance of <bootloader>), have different Class objects for the type he.tools.ant.helper.ProjectHelper2$RootHandler.setDocumentLocator(Lorg/xml/sax/Locator;)V used in the signature
        at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.ProjectHelper2.parseUnknownElement(ProjectHelper2.java:131)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.ProjectHelper2.parseAntlibDescriptor(ProjectHelper2.java:111)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Antlib.createAntlib(Antlib.java:91)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Definer.loadAntlib(Definer.java:440)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Definer.execute(Definer.java:292)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.ComponentHelper.checkNamespace(ComponentHelper.java:869)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.ComponentHelper.getDefinition(ComponentHelper.java:308)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.ComponentHelper.createComponent(ComponentHelper.java:285)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.ComponentHelper.createComponent(ComponentHelper.java:264)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.makeObject(UnknownElement.java:417)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.maybeConfigure(UnknownElement.java:163)
        at groovy.util.AntBuilder.performTask(AntBuilder.java:255)
        at groovy.util.AntBuilder.nodeCompleted(AntBuilder.java:220)
        at groovy.util.BuilderSupport.doInvokeMethod(BuilderSupport.java:147)
        at groovy.util.AntBuilder.doInvokeMethod(AntBuilder.java:170)
        at groovy.util.BuilderSupport.invokeMethod(BuilderSupport.java:64)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBuilder.invokeMethod(GantBuilder.java:99)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:45)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.initializeGantBinding(GantBinding.groovy:108)
        at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.<init>(GantBinding.groovy:42)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.executeScriptWithCaching(GrailsScriptRunner.java:424)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.callPluginOrGrailsScript(GrailsScriptRunner.java:410)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.executeCommand(GrailsScriptRunner.java:374)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.executeCommand(GrailsScriptRunner.java:339)
        ... 6 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 10.351 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-05-23T12:47:31+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 10M/27M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.grails:grails-maven-plugin:2.2.4:clean (default-clean) on project XXX: Forked Grails VM exited with error -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.grails:grails-maven-plugin:2.2.4:clean (default-clean) on project XXX: Forked Grails VM exited with error
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:108)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:76)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:361)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:213)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:157)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Forked Grails VM exited with error
        at org.grails.maven.plugin.AbstractGrailsMojo.runGrails(AbstractGrailsMojo.java:388)
        at org.grails.maven.plugin.AbstractGrailsMojo.runGrails(AbstractGrailsMojo.java:308)
        at org.grails.maven.plugin.GrailsCleanMojo.execute(GrailsCleanMojo.java:35)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:133)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
        ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Forked Grails VM exited with error
        at org.grails.maven.plugin.tools.ForkedGrailsRuntime.fork(ForkedGrailsRuntime.java:117)
        at org.grails.maven.plugin.AbstractGrailsMojo.runGrails(AbstractGrailsMojo.java:386)
        ... 23 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Please, could you help me?

D:\dev>java -version
java version "1.7.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_25-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)

D:\dev>grails -version

Grails version: 2.2.4

D:\dev>mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.2.1 (ea8b2b07643dbb1b84b6d16e1f08391b666bc1e9; 2014-02-14T18:37:52+01:00)
Maven home: C:\apache-maven-3.2.1\bin..
Java version: 1.7.0_45, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\glassfish4\jdk7\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1250
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "x86", family: "windows"

Thanks!

Comment: I'm having the same issue with grails 2.4.3

Comment: Having the same issue with 2.4.2 . Any fix has been found?

Answer (score 3):

I believe you need to add the exclusion of `xml-apis` to your `http-builder` dependency.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder</groupId>
        <artifactId>http-builder</artifactId>
        <version>0.5.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <!-- ######################################### -->
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>xml-resolver</groupId>
                <artifactId>xml-resolver</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
                <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a maven clean . As you out put dectates.

Do a refresh dependency first then

```
grails clean

mvn clean

grails create-pom

grails referseh dependency // this not command line use your STS /GGTS MENU
```

Comment: grails maven-clean isn't valid either?

Comment: maven clean or mvn clean if u have maven installed