# gradle multiproject build for grails - cant assemble project with hibernate dependency

Tags: grails, gradle

i have built a multi project gradle build for grails project and - i'm getting a strange error when i add the hibernate4 dependency -

without this the project builds fine - i can use the grails assemble task on the route project - works fine and then run it and connect .

however as soon as i add the hibernate4 dependency and try and assemble i get this

```
[sts] -----------------------------------------------------
[sts] Starting Gradle build for the following tasks: 
[sts]      assemble
[sts] -----------------------------------------------------
:MyItilApp:war
|Loading Grails 2.4.4
|Configuring classpath
Error |
Fatal error forking Grails JVM: null
Error |
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Error |
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
Error |
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
Error |
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
Error |
    at org.grails.launcher.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:57)
Error |
    at org.grails.launcher.context.DelegatingGrailsLaunchContext.launch(DelegatingGrailsLaunchContext.java:409)
Error |
    at org.grails.launcher.ReflectiveGrailsLauncher.launch(ReflectiveGrailsLauncher.java:32)
Error |
    at org.grails.launcher.InProcessGrailsLauncher.launch(InProcessGrailsLauncher.java:27)
Error |
    at org.grails.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:62)
Error |
    at org.grails.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:38)
Error |
**Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError:** loader constraint violation: when resolving overridden method "org.apache.tools.ant.helper.ProjectHelper2$RootHandler.setDocumentLocator(Lorg/xml/sax/Locator;)V" the class loader (instance of org/grails/launcher/rootloader/RootLoader) of the current class, org/apache/tools/ant/helper/ProjectHelper2$RootHandler, and its superclass loader (instance of <bootloader>), have different Class objects for the type andler.setDocumentLocator(Lorg/xml/sax/Locator;)V used in the signature
Error |
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.ProjectHelper2.parseUnknownElement(ProjectHelper2.java:131)
Error |
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.ProjectHelper2.parseAntlibDescriptor(ProjectHelper2.java:111)
Error |
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Antlib.createAntlib(Antlib.java:91)
Error |
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Definer.loadAntlib(Definer.java:440)
Error |
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Definer.execute(Definer.java:292)
Error |
    at org.apache.tools.ant.ComponentHelper.checkNamespace(ComponentHelper.java:877)
Error |
    at org.apache.tools.ant.ComponentHelper.getDefinition(ComponentHelper.java:308)
Error |
    at org.apache.tools.ant.ComponentHelper.createComponent(ComponentHelper.java:285)
Error |
    at org.apache.tools.ant.ComponentHelper.createComponent(ComponentHelper.java:264)
Error |
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.makeObject(UnknownElement.java:417)
Error |
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.maybeConfigure(UnknownElement.java:163)
Error |
    at groovy.util.AntBuilder.performTask(AntBuilder.java:314)
Error |
    at groovy.util.AntBuilder.nodeCompleted(AntBuilder.java:264)
Error |
    at groovy.util.BuilderSupport.doInvokeMethod(BuilderSupport.java:147)
Error |
    at groovy.util.AntBuilder.doInvokeMethod(AntBuilder.java:203)
Error |
    at groovy.util.BuilderSupport.invokeMethod(BuilderSupport.java:64)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBuilder.invokeMethod(GantBuilder.java:99)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:45)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.initializeGantBinding(GantBinding.groovy:108)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.<init>(GantBinding.groovy:42)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.executeScriptWithCaching(GrailsScriptRunner.java:430)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.callPluginOrGrailsScript(GrailsScriptRunner.java:416)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.executeCommand(GrailsScriptRunner.java:380)
Error |
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.executeCommand(GrailsScriptRunner.java:347)
Error |
    ... 10 more
:MyItilApp:war FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':MyItilApp:war'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 11.931 secs
[sts] Build failed
org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Could not execute build using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.1-bin.zip'.
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ResultHandlerAdapter.onFailure(ResultHandlerAdapter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:57)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.
```

here is my top level build.gradle file (tried a downloading via hibernate-core and get same problem

```
import org.grails.gradle.plugin.tasks.GrailsTask


buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {url "http://repo.grails.org/grails/core"}
    }

    dependencies {
      classpath "org.grails:grails-gradle-plugin:2.1.1"
    }
}

subprojects {


    //if grails-app is in subproject apply the grails-app plugin to that project
    if (project.file ("grails-app").exists()) {
        apply plugin: 'grails'

        repositories {
            grails.central()
            mavenCentral()
        }

        dependencies {
            runtime "org.grails.plugins:tomcat:8.0.14.1" // No container is deployed by default, so add this
            //compile 'org.grails.plugins:resources:1.2.13' // deprecated for asset-plugin
            compile "org.grails.plugins:asset-pipeline:1.9.9"
            compile "org.grails.plugins:scaffolding:2.1.2"
            compile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate4:4.3.6.1" //add hibernate
            //compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-core:4.3.7.Final" //add hibernate
            compile "org.grails.plugins:database-migration:1.4.0"
            compile 'org.grails.plugins:cache:1.1.8' //, "org.grails.plugins:cache-ehcache:1.0.4"

            runtime "org.grails.plugins:jquery:1.11.1"

            /*


            compile 'org.grails.plugins:webxml:1.4.1' 
            */

            //testCompile 'junit:junit:4.8.2'
            // testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.+'
        }

        //grails class added by the grails plugin - set its properties
        grails {
            grailsVersion = '2.4.4'
            groovyVersion = '2.3.7'
            springLoadedVersion '1.2.1'
        }

        //make sure we have enough build space      
        tasks.withType (org.grails.gradle.plugin.tasks.GrailsTask) {Task t ->
            t.jvmOptions {
                jvmArgs "-Xms512m", "-Xmx4g",  "-XX:MaxPermSize=512m"
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        apply plugin: 'groovy'
    }

    apply plugin: 'eclipse'


    group = 'com.softwood'
    version = '0.1-SNAPSHOT'

    /*
    jar {
        manifest.attributes provider: 'my cool company'
    }
    */
}
```

Any body knows what this is and how i can fix it - i'm pretty close now but seem to get a build with hibernate going.  appreciate any insight  and fix

Comment: I am not sure, but Gradle 2.1 use Groovy 2.3.6, and you specify for grails groovyVersion = '2.3.7' and can become dependencies conflict

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27345822/2152970) indicates that 'xml-apis' needs to be excluded. Also change the scope to `runtime`:

```
runtime('org.grails.plugins:hibernate4:4.3.6.1') {
        exclude module: 'xml-apis'
}
```